# How to get landmarks from current location using google map in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am creating an application in which I am taking current location's latitudes and longitudes as input.I want to know that ,is it possible through google maps service to get nearby landmarks information along with their respective latitudes and longitudes by passing current locations latitudes and longitudes ?
If there is any service like this that you know please share it.
It will be appreciated .
Thanks in advanced!!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YEs you can do this by saving somelandmarks earlier and when user reach near to that location it shows that which landmark is near to that place..

Comment: Can you tell me the exact URL that I can use for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what landmarks you are looking for but you can use the MKReverseGeocoder to get location information (city, street etc). You can also use [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/)

Comment: Landmarks means nearby famous places which will also be provided by google's service.